# Virtualbox loses USB connectivity with SmartCard Reader

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, virtualbox, smartcard

I'm running VirtualBox inside Ubuntu 13.10 and having issues with USB connection stability.
Guest operating system is Debian 7.0 and the USB device I'm trying to work with is a ACS USB card reader (ACR38T to be exact). I've installed VirtualBox extensions, enabled USB 2.0 and created appropriate filters for the device. When I plug the device, the reader is recognized by the guest and opensc-tool -l gives the reader. Card presence is also detected. When I run any command that talks with the smart card, command times out and card connectivity is lost.

After this, I can list the card reader but card cannot be detected. I've tried with another readers with different cards and issue persists.

Can anyone with experience in this matter help me?